# Bootstrap modal closing on WTForm Submit - doesn't display errors - Flask

Tags: flask, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal, flask-wtforms

When building my HTML code for my flask project, my modal closes on submission even if there are errors on submission. I can't find a way of keeping the modal showing if there are errors.

I tried to add some JavaScript but I kept getting errors and then the submit button wouldn't work at all. Also for some reason $.path jQuery commands wouldn't work (I think its maybe due to the fact I'm on a local server?)

Any help is much appreciated.

```
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-info btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"><i class="fas fa-plus icon"></i>Add Training</button>
  <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog form-width">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <span>Add Training</span>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
            <fieldset class="form-group">
              <legend>Add training to your record</legend>
              <br>
              <div class="form-group form-grid">
                {{ form.training_course.label() }}
                {% if form.training_course.errors %}
                  {{ form.training_course(class="form-control form-control-sm is-invalid") }}
                  <div class="invalid-feedback">
                    {% for error in form.training_course.errors %}
                      <span>{{ error }}</span>
                    {% endfor %}
                  </div>
                {% else %}
                  {{ form.training_course(class="form-control form-control-sm") }}
                {% endif %}
              </div>
              <div class="form-group form-grid">
                {{ form.training_provider.label() }}
                {% if form.training_provider.errors %}
                  {{ form.training_provider(class="form-control form-control-sm is-invalid") }}
                  <div class="invalid-feedback">
                    {% for error in form.training_provider.errors %}
                      <span>{{ error }}</span>
                    {% endfor %}
                  </div>
                {% else %}
                  {{ form.training_provider(class="form-control form-control-sm") }}
                {% endif %}
              </div>
              <div class="form-group form-grid">
                {{ form.date.label() }}
                {% if form.date.errors %}
                  {{ form.date(class="form-control form-control-sm is-invalid") }}
                  <div class="invalid-feedback">
                    {% for error in form.date.errors %}
                      <span>{{ error }}</span>
                    {% endfor %}
                  </div>
                {% else %}
                  {{ form.date(class="form-control form-control-sm") }}
                {% endif %}
              </div>
              <div class="form-group form-grid">
                {{ form.cpd.label() }}
                {% if form.cpd.errors %}
                  {{ form.cpd(class="form-control form-control-sm is-invalid", placeholder="CPD Hours") }}
                  <div class="invalid-feedback">
                    {% for error in form.cpd.errors %}
                      <span>{{ error }}</span>
                    {% endfor %}
                  </div>
                {% else %}
                  {{ form.cpd(class="form-control form-control-sm", placeholder="CPD Hours") }}
                {% endif %}
              </div>
              <div class="form-group form-grid">
                {{ form.certificate.label() }}
                {% if form.certificate.errors %}
                  {{ form.certificate(class="form-control form-control-sm is-invalid", style="padding-bottom:30px;") }}
                  <div class="invalid-feedback">
                    {% for error in form.certificate.errors %}
                      <span>{{ error }}</span>
                    {% endfor %}
                  </div>
                {% else %}
                  {{ form.certificate(class="form-control form-control-sm", style="padding-bottom:30px;") }}
                {% endif %}
              </div>
            </fieldset>
            <div class="form-group" >
              {{ form.submit(class="btn btn-outline-info") }}
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

The JavaScript I tried to use but didn't work due to the error (Uncaught TypeError: $.post is not a function - despite the fact I have jQuery) is:

```
$('#submit').click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var url = "{{ url_for('training.completed_training') }}";
  $.post(url, data=$('#modForm').serialize(), function(data) {
    if (data.status == 'ok') {
      $('#myModal').modal('hide');
      location.reload();
    }
    else {
      $('#myModal .modal-content').html(data);
    }
})
});
```

Comment: Hey Saif, welcome to Stack Overflow! Is your error happening on the server or in the browser? Can you supply a stack trace of the error?

Comment: Hi Jon, it jQuery error is the following: scripts.js:18 Uncaught TypeError: $.post is not a function
    at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> (scripts.js:18)
    at HTMLInputElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js:2)
    at HTMLInputElement.v.handle (jquery.min.js:2).    The main issue is the fact the modal disappears when submitted even if it has errors

Comment: Hi Saif (and welcome!),
about the jQuery error, is the click binding correctly inside a $(document).ready() function? (I myself have forgot about this sometimes)
About the modal closing, check what is being received from the server, is the route you're hitting sending the expected data?

Comment: Yep I have but still doesn't work!

Comment: The validation errors (eg wrong file extension submitted in form) show in the modal but the modal closes on submit so you have to reopen the modal to see the validation errors. I want it to stay up if there are validation errors

Comment: I no longer have the above error - however, the validation no longer works at all! Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using jQuery to check if the error message class was present in the HTML and if it was, I used jQuery to reopen the modal.